# TextView goes beyound the ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, android-constraintlayout

I would like to get a effect dotted text(ellipsis property) - both textView in this same line, but I have problem with ConstraintLayout.

In first TextView if I have long text, my second textView going to off screen. 
I would like to block second textView on the end of layout and dotted 1st textView.
It is possible ?

Screens:

[short text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAQxy.png)

[long text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQh7M.png)

xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#00D54C4C"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="longTextlongTextlongTextlongTextlongTextlong"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="85dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="123456789"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="85dp" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Add your current layout xml to the question

Comment: @DanielNugent done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constraints aren't correct as you don't have an end constraint. The following should resolve that issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="#00D54C4C"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="longTextlongTextlongTextlongTextlongTextlong"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="85dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="123456789"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="85dp" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

That however still leaves you with some fairly gnarly layout code that isn't too great. There is never a good reason to have nested `ConstraintLayout`s so I'd recommend refactoring it to be something like this (which will still give you same end result):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="longTextlongTextlongTextlongTextlongTextlong"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="123456789"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The above also includes vertical constraints (`constraintTop_...`) which will ensure the layout displays correctly at runtime and will also resolve the IDE warning you had with the code previously.

And then from there to get the ellipsize effect you just need to add the following attributes to your `TextView`: `android:ellipsize="end"` and `android:lines="1"`

The final XML would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="longTextlongTextlongTextlongTextlongTextlonglongTextlongTextlongTextlongTextlongTextlong"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="123456789"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

One thing to note: this does remove the margin you had previously. Making use of `Guideline` you are able to add the margins/padding you wanted by adding a start and end `Guideline` which has a `vertical` orientation. The final-final version of the layout would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineStart"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineEnd"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="longTextlongTextlongTextlongTextlongTextlonglongTextlongTextlongTextlongTextlongTextlong"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guidelineEnd"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="123456789"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guidelineEnd"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Having TextViews On Same Line**

If you want to have the `TextView`s on the same line you can use another `Guideline` to include where the first should stop and the second should begin. In this example the guideline is set at the halfway point using `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".5"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineStart"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineCenter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineEnd"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="longTextlongTextlong"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineCenter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="123456789"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineCenter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guidelineEnd"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: your 1st block of code didn't work :( first textview is on the second textview and nothing to see

Comment: @san_francisco you should probably use the last one. Your original code doesn't have vertical constraints so it will place it on top of the second text view. The first snippet was just an example to solve the issue that your text wasn't be concatenated.

Comment: both text view need to be in this same lane

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you are trying to do? Should the first text view have a maximum width? Without a mockup of what you are trying to do it will be difficult to follow through just a written example.

Comment: @san_francisco I included another solution which allows you to have them on the same line by adding an additional Guideline.

Comment: yea, something like that ;) but if my text in 1st textView has only 1 char, 2nd textView starting still from half size of layout, I would like to assign my 2nd textView to 1st textView (2nd textView always start from end 1st textView), is it possible ?

Comment: Just using constraints, no it wouldn't be possible. Using a `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight` also doesn't appear possible for your use case. The design you're describing sounds like really strange UX though and would be curious why exactly you need to do this. It seems like you'd have an easier time with just one TextView and making use of a `SpannableString` for more complicated formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your text view you want to ellipsize(...)

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: what is the result after you add these 2 values?